# How to define different vars for different hosts in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to define different variables for different hosts? like:

```
- hosts:
    server_a:
      var_a: "xxx"
    server_b:
      var_a: "yyy"
  roles:
    - some_role
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I found out:

```
- hosts:
    - server_a (or a group of hosts)
    - server_b
  roles:
    - some_role
  vars:
    var_a: |
      {{
        {
          'server_a_ip': [
            'xxx'
          ],
          'server_b_ip': [
            'yyy'
          ]
        }[inventory_hostname]
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Host (and group) variables are not stored in the playbook. They are stored separately, in the inventory file itself, or in files in a directory `host_vars` or `group_vars` relative to the inventory file. These files are named after the host or group for which they contain variables.

See [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) in the Ansible documentation for a more complete description of the variable files.

Comment: Thanks, please see my answer. This is what works currently for me, but it is hard to manage when multiple variables are needed and no user's comments are supported near the values.

Comment: Good God, that looks like a nightmare!